# WebStorm rails code highlight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, erb, webstorm

I'm studying Ruby on rails and I choose WebStorm as IDE to start this new adventure.

Now I'm facing on my first detail to fix... I would like to render the .html.erb files without the red underline. I'm looking around, googleing, and searching through the WebStorm plugins but I cannot find the correct one...

Here is the image about it:

[image]

Then I now there many useful plugins for WebStorm but I cannot find it, for example one of this is the auto-complete for the html elements. You can simply write `div.my-class` and it transform it in `<div class="my-class"></div>`.

Can you help me? And do you know any other very useful WS plugin for languages like javascript, KO, Angular, HTML, CSS, LESS, GRUNT and Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm is a JavaScript IDE.

You should have gone for RubyMine. It's a Ruby on Rails IDE built by the same people:

http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Alternatively, get IntelliJ IDEA and install the Ruby / Rails / JavaScript / etc plugins:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/